# How to give a variable a random value in javascript

Tags: javascript, random

How would I give a variable a random value in javascript?

I can do this:

```
var myMake = ["Chevy","Subaru","Kia","Honda","Toyota"];

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);

var rand = myMake[x];

alert(rand);
```

which gets the desired effect, giving the variable `rand` a random value of one of these:

Chevy, Subaru, Kia, Honda, Toyota

but would there be a way to make a function/method that does something like this?:

```
var rand = randVal("Chevy", "Subaru", "Kia", "Honda", "Toyota");
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function randVal(){
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arguments.length);
  return arguments[x];
}
```

the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an array like object that refers gives a list of all supplied arguments to a function.

Comment: from where the `arguments` coming from?

Comment: Impossible to be first argument because 1 can not equal zero.

Comment: @epascarello I just tested it and I get all the possible results and no undefined

Comment: @user3063875 great, don't forget to accept the answer; this allows someone else to know what the correct answer was.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different!

```
var x = ["Chevy","Subaru","Kia","Honda","Toyota"].sort(function() {
   return 0.5 - Math.random();
})[0];

alert(x);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zcBJ/)

And as a function, but accepting an `Array`

```
var randMe = function ( me ) {
    if ( me ) {
        return me.sort(function() {
          return 0.5 - Math.random();
        })[0];
    }
}

alert(randMe(['a','b','c']));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zcBJ/1/)

And some prototyping as well

```
Array.prototype.rand = function() { 
   return this.sort(function() {
     return 0.5 - Math.random();
   })[0];
}

alert(['a','b','c'].rand());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zcBJ/2/)

Also the actual shuffle function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/1658526).

Comment: well it is not a function and it is a waste of time if the OP does not need the whole set.

Comment: Yes it works, but it is slow http://jsperf.com/testrandomvssortarray Written based on how the OP is calling the function. Not passing in an Array.

Comment: @epascarello oh, actually you're `slice`ing that also ... I didn't notice that first ... but thank you anyways!

Comment: http://jsperf.com/testrandomvssortarray made a case where an array is passed in. The solution is great if you need multiple random values out of the array, but lacks when you need just one. I personally like the solution for card type of shuffling.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for the explanation and jspref as well ... I guess I should use it more often!

Answer (score -4):

You can do that very easy with jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $.rand = function(arg) {
        if ($.isArray(arg)) {
            return arg[$.rand(arg.length)];
        } else if (typeof arg === "number") {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * arg);
        } else {
            return 4;  // chosen by fair dice roll
        }
    };
    })(jQuery);

    var items = ["Chevy","Subaru","Kia","Honda","Toyota"];
    var item = $.rand(items);
```

Comment: There is no need for jQuery here to write a function!

Comment: I need jQuery for "   if ($.isArray(arg)) { "

Comment: Kill a fly with a aircraft.

Comment: You added more requirements than what the OP wanted and the OP is not passing in an array to the function!